# pgAdmin4 not restoring since upgrading to 4.2.2

Tags: postgresql, restore, pgadmin-4

Admittedly, I am fairly new to postgresql and pgadmin, but after spending a day learning it, with pgadmin4.4.1 I was able to backup tables and restore them in various different formats, currently, the format of choice is plain text, so that I can actually read the backup file to see what it is doing and also my database is tiny, but large enough to not want to type in every entry by hand.

Since updating to pgadmin4.4.2, the restore function does not work. I provides a green box saying restore job created, yet no data is added to the database. This was not the case yesterday, it would just restore the data.

Does anyone know what defaults might possibly have changed in the update that will be preventing my restore job from actually running? I am assuming that it is created and waiting in a queue somewhere that I can't find in order to actually run the backup.

Here is the last error from the log file. Apologies for the delay in replying.

```
019-02-08 17:59:06,942: ERROR   pgadmin:    'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/pgAdmin 4.app/Contents/Resources/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Applications/pgAdmin 4.app/Contents/Resources/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/Applications/pgAdmin 4.app/Contents/Resources/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_login.py", line 792, in decorated_view
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Applications/pgAdmin 4.app/Contents/Resources/web/pgadmin/misc/bgprocess/__init__.py", line 61, in index
    return make_response(response=BatchProcess.list())
  File "/Applications/pgAdmin 4.app/Contents/Resources/web/pgadmin/misc/bgprocess/processes.py", line 610, in list
    desc = desc.message
  File "/Applications/pgAdmin 4.app/Contents/Resources/web/pgadmin/tools/backup/__init__.py", line 145, in message
    port = html.safe_str(port)
  File "/Applications/pgAdmin 4.app/Contents/Resources/web/pgadmin/utils/html.py", line 35, in safe_str
    return cgi.escape(x)
  File "/Applications/pgAdmin 4.app/Contents/Resources/venv/lib/python3.6/cgi.py", line 1056, in escape
    s = s.replace("&", "&amp;") # Must be done first!
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

Comment: Can you check the log if there's an error? Linux/MacOS: ~/.pgadmin/pgadmin4.log & Windows: %APPDATA%\pgAdmin\pgadmin4.log

Comment: What is port value in your server properties dialog, looks like the port is passed as null hence it is throwing an error, can you provide the screenshots of the values present in each tab of server properties dialog. Ref: https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/dev/server_dialog.html

Comment: Ah, yes this on my development server currently, so this is 127.0.0.1:8000, apologies, i am only on this project one day in the week. I don't have the luxury of staging on this project, so it is dev laptop and main server. This issue arose on my Development environment. I can post anything you need today to help.